# percentage of confidance on desion trees results

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking towards a solution where classification algorithms produce output with some confidence value. but I am confused whether classification algorithms are able to produce results with percentage of confidence? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some classification algorithms can indeed return a probability distribution over the considered classes (see Wikipedia on [probabilistic classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_classification)).

In the topic of your question you're asking about Decision Trees. Well, these have their limitations in terms of providing probability estimates (see this [paper on probability estimates from decision trees](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.324.132&rep=rep1&type=pdf)).

In case you would like to play around with this, it's very easy to start with scikit-learn:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# training samples
X = np.array([[1, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 1]])

# target values for training samples
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1])

dtc.fit(X, y)

print 'Class probabilities for training samples:'
print dtc.predict_proba(X)
print 'Probabilities for previously unseen samples:'
for sample in ((1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0)):
     print 'Sample {}. Result: {}'.format(sample, dtc.predict_proba(sample))
```

This code returns following results:

```
Class probabilities for training samples:
[[ 1.   0. ]
 [ 1.   0. ]
 [ 0.5  0.5]
 [ 0.5  0.5]]
Probabilities for previously unseen samples:
Sample (1, 0, 1). Result: [[ 0.5  0.5]]
Sample (0, 0, 1). Result: [[ 0.5  0.5]]
Sample (1, 1, 1). Result: [[ 0.5  0.5]]
Sample (0, 0, 0). Result: [[ 1.  0.]]
```

At this scale the results are easily interpretable:

- a sample of features (1, 1, 0) is classified as 0 with 100% probability
- a sample of features (0, 0, 1) is classified 50/50 as 0 or 1. etc.

This brings us to an important question of [how accurate is your model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34936/41317)?